# Set DOMAIN for existing column

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgres-14, sql-domain

I have an existing table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.data (
    id integer,
    name text,
    sell_value real)
);
```

and I define a domain as:

```
CREATE DOMAIN dataDomain AS TEXT
CHECK(name = ANY ('{joe, john, jack}'::text[]));
```

How can I apply the domain to the column "name"?

EDIT: I have to apply the domain in a existing table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use it like any other type:

```
create table public.data (
    id integer,
    name dataDomain,
    ...
);
```

Documentation with examples is [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html).

By the way, be aware that PostgreSQL folds identifiers to lower case unless you double-quote them: so `dataDomain` and `datadomain` are identical, but different from `"dataDomain"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ALTER COLUMN` fro apply domain policy:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
    id integer,
    name text,
    sell_value real
);

CREATE DOMAIN data_domain AS TEXT CHECK(VALUE = ANY ('{joe, john, jack}'::text[]));

ALTER TABLE data
ALTER COLUMN name SET DATA TYPE data_domain;
```

[online sql editor](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/21c06138e0f9ad0b28a1ed11f0d3440f/)